# SQL alias gives invalid column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using the following SQL expression but I'm getting an error.

```
select
  CampaignCustomer.CampaignCustomerID,
  convert(varchar, CampaignCustomer.ModifiedDate, 111) as startdate,
  CampaignCustomer.CampaignID,
  CampaignCustomer.CampaignCallStatusID,
  CampaignCustomer.UserID,
  CampaignCustomerSale.Value,
  Users.Name
from CampaignCustomer
  inner join CampaignCustomerSale
    on CampaignCustomer.CampaignCustomerID = CampaignCustomerSale.CampaignCustomerID
  inner join Users
    on CampaignCustomer.UserID = Users.UserID
where
  CampaignCustomer.CampaignCallStatusID = 21
  and CampaignCustomer.startdate = '2011/11/22'      <------- THIS
order by
  startdate desc,
  Users.Name asc
```

Error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'startdate'.

I can't recognize my alias name `startdate` in the WHERE clause, but it can in my `ORDER BY` clause. What's wrong?

**Edit:**
And no, it is not possible for me to change the datatype to `date` instead of `datetime`. The time is needed elsewhere. But in this case, I need only to get all posts on a specific date and I really don't care about what time of the date the `modifieddate` is :)

Maybe another method is needed instead of convert()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Aliases in Where Clause or an Alternative Option?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705470/using-aliases-in-where-clause-or-an-alternative-option)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't use column alias in `WHERE` clause.

---

Change it to:

```
where
  CampaignCustomer.CampaignCallStatusID = 21
  and convert(varchar, CampaignCustomer.ModifiedDate, 111) = '2011/11/22'
```

Comment: +1 That is still horribly unsargable though. Best to just use `CampaignCustomer.ModifiedDate >= '20111122' and CampaignCustomer.ModifiedDate < '20111123'` instead and abandon the idea of re-using that expression at all.

Comment: Yeah I don't like comparing date type to string type. Would using `DAY(CampaignCustomer.ModifiedDate)=DAY(22) AND MONTH(CampaignCustomer.ModifiedDate)=MONTH(11) AND YEAR(CampaignCustomer.ModifiedDate)=YEAR(2011)` be better to use? Or is that just as bad in terms of performance?

Comment: Just as bad. If the OP is on SQL Server 2008 then `CAST(CampaignCustomer.ModifiedDate AS DATE) = '20111122'` *is* sargable however. The optimiser has special logic for this case.

Comment: @erizias - What does `SELECT @@VERSION` say?

Comment: Damn, forgot it wasn't on my own SQL Server 2008, but on a customers.. SQL Server 2005 :(

Answer (score 4):

Do this:

```
select 
  CampaignCustomer.CampaignCustomerID, 
  convert(varchar, CampaignCustomer.ModifiedDate, 111) as startdate, 
  CampaignCustomer.CampaignID, 
  CampaignCustomer.CampaignCallStatusID, 
  CampaignCustomer.UserID, 
  CampaignCustomerSale.Value, 
  Users.Name 
from CampaignCustomer 
  inner join CampaignCustomerSale 
    on CampaignCustomer.CampaignCustomerID = CampaignCustomerSale.CampaignCustomerID 
  inner join Users 
    on CampaignCustomer.UserID = Users.UserID 
where 
  CampaignCustomer.CampaignCallStatusID = 21 
  and convert(varchar, CampaignCustomer.ModifiedDate, 111) = '2011/11/22'
order by 
  startdate desc, 
  Users.Name asc
```

You need to put in your `where` clause no aliases, and in the above query I replaced your alias with what it represents.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what **version** of SQL Server you're using - but if you're on 2008 or newer, you could use:

```
where
  CampaignCustomer.CampaignCallStatusID = 21
  and CAST(CampaignCustomer.ModifiedDate AS DATE) = '20111122'
```

You could cast it to a `DATE` - just for this comparison.

Also: I would recommend to **always** use the ISO-8601 standard format of representing a date if you need to compare a date to string - ISO-8601 defines a date as `YYYYMMDD` and is the only format in SQL Server that will always work - no matter what language/regional settings you have. Any other string representation of a date is always subject to settings in your SQL Server - it might work for you, but I bet for someone else, it will break....

Comment: It is not my own server, but it's SQL Server 2005 :(