# "Invalid column name" error in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, where-clause

What's wrong with this code?

I get this error:

> Invalid column name 'Distance'

Code:

```
SELECT 
    Company.CompanyId as Id,
    ( 6371  * acos( cos( radians(47.8423155) ) * cos( radians( Company.Latitude  ) ) * cos( radians( Company.Longitude  ) - radians(35.232933) ) + sin( radians(47.8423155) ) * sin( radians( Company.Latitude ) ) ) ) AS Distance
FROM 
    Company 
INNER JOIN  
    Product ON Company.CompanyId = Product.CompanyId 
WHERE
    Distance< 5000   
ORDER BY
    Distance
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL alias gives invalid column name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243283/sql-alias-gives-invalid-column-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the select inside subselect

```
   select * from(SELECT 
    Company.CompanyId as Id,
    ( 6371  * acos( cos( radians(47.8423155) ) * cos( radians( Company.Latitude  ) ) * cos( radians( Company.Longitude  ) - radians(35.232933) ) + sin( radians(47.8423155) ) * sin( radians( Company.Latitude ) ) ) ) AS Distance
FROM 
    Company 
INNER JOIN  
    Product ON (Company.CompanyId = Product.CompanyId) 
) AS P
WHERE
    P.Distance< 5000   
ORDER BY
    P.Distance;
```

The inner subquery returns the function on basis of which you are filtering with the alias Distance.

Comment: it seems you are right, but I got a error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'."

Comment: Maybe improper paranthesis. Wait. Try out now

Comment: Used an alias. Hope this would solve the issue. There are some alias related differences in syntax of Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: Still got a -1 from somewhere :-P

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the [rdbms](/questions/tagged/rdbms) you're using, some RDBMSs don't allow referring to column aliases in the `where` and `order by` columns. Just use the actual column names:

```
SELECT      Company.CompanyId as Id,
            Company.VisitCount AS myVisitCount 
FROM        Company
INNER JOIN  Product ON  Company.CompanyId = Product.CompanyId 
WHERE       Company.VisitCount < 5000   
ORDER BY    Company.VisitCount
```

Comment: you are right, but I have Updating my question , look at this distance , please :|

Comment: @user5740086 the same principle still applies

Comment: I want to return distance , so you are saying to use"( 6371........ ) " at both of select and where, is this normally ?

Comment: @user5740086 that would work. The alternative is to have the calculation in a subqeury and apply the `where` and `order by` clauses in the outer query.

Comment: it's works, but using two times of this, is normally ? "( 6371  * acos( cos( radians(47.8423155) ) * cos( radians( Company.Latitude  ) ) * cos( radians( Company.Longitude  ) - radians(35.232933) ) + sin( radians(47.8423155) ) * sin( radians( Company.Latitude ) ) ) )"