# SQLAlchemy Python 3.8 work with renamed columns

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sql-server

I'm trying to execute the following query :

```
# query
lookback = 5

query = f"""
SELECT
    token,
    DATEDIFF(day, dt_utc, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS dt_diff
FROM
    dbo.TokenRegistry
WHERE
    dt_diff < {lookback}
"""
```

And unfortunately i obtain the following error :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S22', "[42S22] 
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
Invalid column name 'dt_diff'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: 
SELECT
   token,
   DATEDIFF(day, dt_utc, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as dt_diff
FROM
   dbo.TokenRegistry
WHERE
   dt_diff < 11
]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

My config is the following :

```
Python 3.8
sqlalchemy.__version__ = '1.4.41'
pyodbc.version = '4.0.34'
```

Workaround (efficient ? )

```
SELECT
*  
FROM
(
  SELECT
     *,
     DATEDIFF(second, dt_utc, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS dt_diff
  FROM
     dbo.TokenRegistry
) DATA
WHERE
  dt_diff < 11
```

Can you please help with that ?
Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a SQLAlchemy error, this is a SQL Server error. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243283/sql-alias-gives-invalid-column-name .

Comment: sql server doesn't allow aliases in HAVING  or WHERE so your approach is ok or use ' HAVING `DATEDIFF(day, dt_utc, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) < 11`