# Using subquery's alias in a WHERE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

I'm trying to use an alias created in a SELECT in a WHERE statement. It doesn't work and I read why in another SO question.

How do I make this work without repeating the subquery?

```
SELECT p.PatientID, p.PatientType, p.AccountNumber,
    p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName PatientFullName,
    p.CreatedDate, DATEDIFF(hour, p.CreatedDate, GETDATE()) TotalTime,
    (SELECT AVG(BGValue)
        FROM BloodGlucose
        WHERE PatientID = p.PatientID) AvgBG
FROM Patients p
WHERE AvgBG > 60;
```

This works:

```
SELECT p.PatientID, p.PatientType, p.AccountNumber,
    p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName PatientFullName, p.CreatedDate,
    DATEDIFF(hour, p.CreatedDate, GETDATE()) TotalTime,
    (SELECT AVG(BGValue) FROM BloodGlucose WHERE PatientID = p.PatientID) AvgBG
FROM Patients p
WHERE (SELECT AVG(BGValue) FROM BloodGlucose WHERE PatientID = p.PatientID) > 60;
```

But I don't want to repeat that subquery. And I suspect it has poor performance.

Comment: If you are concerned about performance you should not be writing correlated subqueries to begin with!

Comment: That is the reason of my last sentence! I know it's not performance-wise and I'm asking for another solution.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705470/using-aliases-in-where-clause-or-an-alternative-option

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using a derived table instead.

```
SELECT p.PatientID, p.PatientType, p.AccountNumber,
    p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName PatientFullName,
    p.CreatedDate, DATEDIFF(hour, p.CreatedDate, GETDATE()) TotalTime,
    bg.AvgBG 
FROM Patients p 
JOIN (SELECT PatientID, AVG(BGValue) AvgBG
    FROM BloodGlucose group by PatientID) BG
ON BG.PatientID = p.PatientID 
WHERE AvgBG > 60;
```

Derived tables work in sets and correlated subqueries work row-by-agonizing-row, that is why mine is faster.

Answer (score 3):

The aliases in the WHERE clause can only come from the FROM clause.  Here is a way to rewrite your query:

```
SELECT p.PatientID, p.PatientType, p.AccountNumber,
       p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName as PatientFullName, p.CreatedDate,
       DATEDIFF(hour, p.CreatedDate, GETDATE()) TotalTime,
       av.AvgBG
FROM Patients p join
     (SELECT PatientId, AVG(BGValue) as AvgBG
      FROM BloodGlucose
      group by PatientID
     ) av
     on p.PatientId = av.PatientId
WHERE av.AvgBG > 60;
```

Comment: It gives me: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "p.PatientID" could not be bound. :-/ Thanks for responding.

Comment: @RGI . . . fixed.  That was supposed to be a group by statement.

Comment: "The aliases in the WHERE clause can only come from the FROM clause" Thank you! That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use *WITH* clause in standard SQL.

```
WITH Subquery AS
(
    Your Code
)
```

And then your code

```
SELECT ....
Subquery As sq
From Patients p
WHERE(subquery)>60
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a common table expression:

```
;WITH CTE (PatientID, PatientType, AccountNumber, PatientFullName, CreatedDate, TotalTime, AvgBG) AS (
    SELECT p.PatientID, p.PatientType, p.AccountNumber, p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName PatientFullName, p.CreatedDate,
    DATEDIFF(hour, p.CreatedDate, GETDATE()) TotalTime,
    (SELECT AVG(BGValue) FROM BloodGlucose WHERE PatientID = p.PatientID) AvgBG
    FROM Patients p
)

SELECT PatientID, PatientType, AccountNumber, PatientFullName, CreatedDate, TotalTime, AvgBG
FROM CTE
WHERE AvgBG > 60
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.PatientID, p.PatientType, p.AccountNumber, p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName PatientFullName, p.CreatedDate, DATEDIFF(hour, p.CreatedDate, GETDATE()) TotalTime, bg.AvgBG  
FROM Patients p  
outer apply (SELECT PatientID, AVG(BGValue) AvgBG   
FROM BloodGlucose where PatientID = p.PatientID  
 group by PatientID ) BG 
 WHERE AvgBG > 60;
```

this should also work pretty quickly

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.PatientID, p.PatientType, p.AccountNumber, p.FirstName p.LastName PatientFullName, p.CreatedDate,
DATEDIFF(hour, p.CreatedDate, GETDATE()) TotalTime, a.AvgBG
FROM Patients p,
(SELECT PatientID, AVG(BGValue) AvgBG
  FROM BloodGlucose
group by PatientID
having AVG(BGValue) > 60) a
where p.PatientID = a.PatientID
```

Comment: You should not ever recommend the use of a SQL Antipattern like an implicit join.

Comment: @HLGEM - Why? it is doing the same job as you did. right? Can you explain for Downvote plz?

Comment: @RGI, I did explain, we do not want to encourage poor coding practices and implicit joins are poor coding practice that was replaced 20 years ago. It is more subject errors such as accidental cross joins and incorrect results if you try to use left joins and inner joins, harder to maintain, and far less clear.

Comment: first time I hear that "implicit joins" are "anti-pattern", and especially "harder to maintain". SQL needs maintenance?! Will you deploy buggy accidental cross-join into production application? Who is going to use SQL console and accidentally run copy-pasted buggy SQL (not retrieved via version control, not tested in QA)? Nobody.