# Grails select specific column and use it in where clause

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm doing a simple query using some math functions (the actual query is more complicated, but even this simple example demonstrates the error):

```
        SELECT 123 as distance,
        c
        FROM MyDomainClass as c
```

And this will return [distance,domain class] pairs. That works fine. However, I want to filter and sort by distance as well.

```
        SELECT 123 as distance,
        c
        FROM MyDomainClass as c
        WHERE distance < 10
```

Unfortunately, it cannot find the 'distance' column in the result set:

```
Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'
```

I turned SQL logging and see the following generated query:

```
select 123 as col_0_0_, ............. where distance<?
```

So I can see the error, but I don't understand why it's using a generated column name 'col_0_0_' in the result set or how I can use this generated name in the where clause.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I figured out the main problem is even in native SQL you cannot use an alias in a where clause. But I'm still having a problem looking for an alternative as the distance calculation is fairly expensive.

Comment: I wound up using a derived table and a native SQL query. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678269/using-subquerys-alias-in-a-where-statement - would be interested in a HQL only solution though