# SQL replace using SELECT and invalid column

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, case, datediff

I have a simple table where the date column `answer_6` (formatted as `varchar(max)` either has a valid date or string `Now`.  I wanted to substitute the `Now` with the current date/time and then calculate the difference. Here is what I did:

```
select 
CASE [answer_6]
   WHEN 'Now' THEN CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE())
   ELSE answer_6 
END as x, 
 answer_6 from [tDataMult] where  DATEDIFF(yy, GETDATE(), [x]) > 5
```

The system give me `invalid column name 'x'`.  If I remove the `DateDiff` `SELECT` statement works fine.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use `select` aliases in your `where` clauses; they aren't recognized. You could duplicate the value in your `where` clause, but hopefully somebody has a more elegant solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Aliases in Where Clause or an Alternative Option?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705470/using-aliases-in-where-clause-or-an-alternative-option)

Comment: In SQL Server, never use `varchar` without a length specifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use aliases in the `WHERE` clause of the same level as it was defined as `WHERE` clause is evaluated *before* the `SELECT` clause. Try the following :

```
SELECT t.* FROM (<...>) t WHERE DATEDIFF(yy, GETDATE(), [t.x]) > 5
```

Instead `<...>` put your query without `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to an alias you've just created in a `WHERE` clause. The easiest way to fix it would just be to turn your original query into a subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
  select 
  CASE [answer_6]
     WHEN 'Now' THEN CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE())
     ELSE answer_6 
  END as x, 
   answer_6 from [tDataMult]
) AS qry
WHERE DATEDIFF(yy, GETDATE(), [x]) > 5
```

Or you could replicate the expression in your `WHERE` clause:

```
select 
CASE [answer_6]
   WHEN 'Now' THEN CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE())
   ELSE answer_6 
END as x, 
 answer_6 from [tDataMult] 
WHERE DATEDIFF(yy, GETDATE(), 
  (CASE [answer_6]
     WHEN 'Now' THEN CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE())
     ELSE answer_6
     END)
  ) > 5
```

Comment: Jeff, awesome, I tried the first version and that worked great, albeit I have another problem.  My column is a varchar(max) that stores the date as 'mm/yyyy'  I am now getting errors on the DATEDIFF, namely during conversion.  Here is what I have:

DATEDIFF(year, GETDATE(), CONVERT(datetime, x)) > 5

The above generates error in convert.  Any ideas?   Again, thanks for the above.

Comment: Never mind, just found out how to do it.  Here is a reference to those that might need it.  The statement below converts mm/yyyy to a valid datetime:

`code`
CAST((SUBSTRING(answer_6,1,2) + '/01' + SUBSTRING(answer_6,3,5)) as datetime)

Answer (score 0):

Column X does not exist in tDataMult table because it is an alias. 
Replace it with answer_6 in DateDiff function.

However, one of the possible value of answer_6 column is varchar format ('Now').
You need to have valid data format to use DATEDIFF function properly. (for example: 'yyyy-mm-dd').