# Using alias in where clause SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Within the declaration of the SQL statement, I have implemented a if/else statement depending on the input of the user. This statement:

```
    if($form['filter']['date'] && $form['filter']['dateTill'] == ""){
        $sql .= '(select results.completed from results where results.client_id = c.id and results.completed IS NOT NULL AND results.completed > "'.$form['filter']['date'].'" order by results.id desc limit 1) AS last_completed_analysis, ';
    } else if($form['filter']['dateTill'] && $form['filter']['dateTill'] == "") {
       $sql .= '(select results.completed from results where results.client_id = c.id and results.completed IS NOT NULL AND results.completed < "'.$form['filter']['dateTill'].'" order by results.id desc limit 1) AS last_completed_analysis, ';
    } else if($form['filter']['dateTill'] && $form['filter']['dateTill']){
        $sql .= '(select results.completed from results where results.client_id = c.id and results.completed IS NOT NULL AND results.completed > "'.$form['filter']['date'].'" AND results.completed <"'.$form['filter']['dateTill'].'" order by results.id desc limit 1) AS last_completed_analysis, ';
    }
    else {
        $sql .= '(select results.completed from results where results.client_id = c.id and results.completed IS NOT NULL order by results.id desc limit 1) AS last_completed_analysis, ';
    }
```

All of these are aliased as `last_completed_analysis`. However, the `is not null` is not working, thus I would want to declare a where clause with the `is not null statement` like:

```
WHERE last_completed_analysis IS NOT NULL
```

However.. this isn't working. I could copy paste the whole declaration of the `last_completed_analysis`, but this code would be too long for me and I know it could be done better... could someone help me declare this where clause?

Comment: Question is not clear, can you make it more clear ?

Comment: You can't use an alias defined in the select in the where clause of the same select.  You could move the where clause to an outer select where clause by wraping the whole select in `SELECT * FROM ()A where last_completed_analysis is not null` and it would work. It has to do with order of operation.  The where executes before the select thus the alias hasn't been set when the were executes; so the where clause alias don't know what last_completed_analysis is in reference to as it's not in scope yet. By moving it to an outer where, the inner select alias has been materialized thus available.

Comment: [Microsoft SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn198336.aspx). and [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) are unrelated database software, with different syntax rules that extended the SQL standard in different ways. They cannot be mixed. Which one do you use?

Comment: **Warning** your code is subject to **SQL Injection**. Never concatenate user-submitted data in your SQL. Please use parameterised queries, or at least escape any data before concatenating it.

Comment: Also, I'd strongly recommend you factorize most of your SQL query and only adjust conditions based on user input.

Comment: @SQLServer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7706045/924077

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use alias in  where condition

you can use alias in order by or in most recent  version in group by but not in where  ..

this because the columns area evaluated in a specific order and  when the where condition is evaluated  the alias are not ( at the moment) resolved

so you should use the full code  eg:

```
  WHERE (select results.completed 
          from results 
          where results.client_id = c.id 
          and results.completed  
          IS NOT NULL order by results.id desc limit 1) IS NOT NULL
```

*and be careful using string concat based un user input ..*

Comment: @AnnaJeanine Please be careful adding user input by concatenating strings to form a query.  It is vulnerable to SQL injection unless you sanitize your inputs.  Someone could quite literally delete your database or access private information with very little effort if this isn't done right.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out Emuevil! I have tried my best in the rest of my query to restrict the user input to only a date type.