# Sql throwing up error on aggregate in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery, average

```
SELECT A.A1, A.B2, A.C2, 
(select AVG(X1.parm) 
 from (VALUES (A.KK1),(A.KK2)) as X1(parm) 
 where X1.parm >110 and X1.parm is not NULL
) as observed           
FROM Table A
WHERE observed > 200
```

This is throwing up error: **Invalid column name 'observed'**
why?

Comment: Because you cannot reference a column alias in the WHERE clause

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: You cannot use an alias in where clause: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7705486/1138946. You have to repeat the expression

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Aliases in Where Clause or an Alternative Option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705470/using-aliases-in-where-clause-or-an-alternative-option)

Comment: FYI SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for over a year now. You should b e looking at upgrade paths urgently, so that you can use a supported version.

Comment: *"yes, please flag the question."* You can flag your own question as a duplicate, if so so wish. it will then be locked immediately (if i recall correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reuse an alias defined in the `select` clause in the `where` clause in the same scope.

A workaround here is a lateral join:

```
select a.a1, a.b2, a.c2, x.observed
from table a
cross apply (
    select avg(x.parm) observed
    from (values (a.kk1),(a.kk2)) as x(parm) 
    where x.parm > 110 and x.parm is not null
) x
where x.observed > 200
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference a column by its alias in the `WHERE`, as the `SELECT` is parsed after the `WHERE`. See [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement).

Move the subquery into the `FROM`:

```sql
SELECT A.A1,
       A.B2,
       A.C2,
       C.observed
FROM [Table] A
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT AVG(X1.parm) AS observed
                  FROM (VALUES (A.KK1),
                               (A.KK2)) X1 (parm)
                  WHERE X1.parm > 110
                    AND X1.parm IS NOT NULL) C
WHERE C.observed > 200;
```

If the subquery might not return any rows, then use an `OUTER APPLY` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answer about logical query processing, the WHERE clause does not have visbibility to the new derived column.

[Read more on Logical query processing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/07/logical-query-processing/)

> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE/ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP
> 12. OFFSET/FETCH

If you want to refer to the column, then you can do in multiple ways. Some approaches are given below:

**Way 1: Leverage CTE**

```sql
;WITH CTE_Table1 AS
(
SELECT A.A1, A.B2, A.C2, 
(select AVG(X1.parm) 
 from (VALUES (A.KK1),(A.KK2)) as X1(parm) 
 where X1.parm >110 and X1.parm is not NULL
) as observed           
FROM Table A
)
SELECT * FROM cte_Table1
WHERE observed > 200
```

**Way 2: Using derived table**

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT A.A1, A.B2, A.C2, 
(select AVG(X1.parm) 
 from (VALUES (A.KK1),(A.KK2)) as X1(parm) 
 where X1.parm >110 and X1.parm is not NULL
) as observed           
FROM Table A) as derived_Table1
WHERE observed > 200
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have common table expressions with SQL Server 2008, so why not simply wrap your existing query in a WITH so that your alias becomes available?:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT A.A1, A.B2, A.C2, 
(select AVG(X1.parm) 
 from (VALUES (A.KK1),(A.KK2)) as X1(parm) 
 where X1.parm >110 and X1.parm is not NULL
) as observed           
FROM Table A
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE observed > 200
```

Unless there's something I'm missing?