# How to reference column by its alias within ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm told that `ROW_NUMBER` is the best way to select the top row from each group, but it doesn't work.  Here is my example

```
SELECT
    TOP 10000
    CASE WHEN var3 IN ('string1', 'string2') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS PosDiag,
    var1, var2, var3, dat4,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY var1 ORDER BY PosDiag DESC) rn 
FROM
    mydb 
ORDER BY var1, PosDiag DESC, dat4 ASC
```

This just throws an error:

> Invalid column name 'PosDiag'

If I remove PosDiag from the `ORDER BY` it still throws the error.  At some point I have to order by both var1 and then PosDiag to bring the PosDiag = 'Y' to the top of each group, when/where it exists, so that the newly created row number will always correspond to row number 1 and can later be extracted.

Comment: You can't reference a column by it's alias within the same scope. Repeat the expression, or use a derived table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Aliases in Where Clause or an Alternative Option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705470/using-aliases-in-where-clause-or-an-alternative-option) (Yes, it's about a `WHERE`, but the solution is identical)

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference aliases defined in the SELECT clause in other alias definitions, etc.

You need to define the alias in a sub-query in order to use it in other expressions.

```
SELECT
  TOP 10000
  posDiag,
  var1, var2, var3, dat4,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY var1 ORDER BY PosDiag DESC) rn 
FROM
(
  SELECT
    mydb.*,
    CASE WHEN var3 IN ('string1', 'string2') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS PosDiag
  FROM
    mydb
)
  mydb 
ORDER BY
  var1,
  PosDiag DESC,
  dat4 ASC
```

Also, bear in mind that SQL is a Declarative Language.  You write an expression and then it is parsed and 'compiled' in to an execution plan.  Just because you have a sub-query to fit the language doesn't mean that the sub-query adds un-necessary processing.

***EDIT:***

Alternative forms...

```
WITH
  mydb AS
(
  SELECT
    mydb.*,
    CASE WHEN var3 IN ('string1', 'string2') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS PosDiag
  FROM
    mydb
)
SELECT
  TOP 10000
  posDiag,
  var1, var2, var3, dat4,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY var1 ORDER BY PosDiag DESC) rn 
FROM
  mydb 
ORDER BY
  var1,
  PosDiag DESC,
  dat4 ASC
```

or...

```
SELECT
  TOP 10000
  posDiag,
  var1, var2, var3, dat4,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY var1 ORDER BY PosDiag DESC) rn 
FROM
  mydb
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT CASE WHEN var3 IN ('string1', 'string2') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
)
  AS translate_var3(PosDiag)
ORDER BY
  var1,
  PosDiag DESC,
  dat4 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

After you set the value for PosDial, try replacing it (PosDiag) with its content (CASE WHEN var3 IN ('string1', 'string2') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END), as it is an alias and its value is not known within the same query:

```
SELECT
    TOP 10000
    CASE WHEN var3 IN ('string1', 'string2') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS PosDiag,
    var1, var2, var3, dat4,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY var1 ORDER BY  CASE WHEN var3 IN ('string1', 'string2') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END DESC) rn 
FROM
    mydb 
ORDER BY var1,  CASE WHEN var3 IN ('string1', 'string2') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END DESC, dat4 ASC
```

Comment: This does, however, mean repeating the same code in multiple places, which breaches the DRY principle...

Comment: @MatBailie, Thx a bunch, it does help me sort out the problem.  This is my simplified version .... unfortunately in real life my CASE WHEN statement is very long and convoluted, but most efficient I can think of!  If SQL doesn't like aliases, then so it must be.

Comment: @JimMaas - It's not that it doesn't like aliases, it's just the order in which everything is evaluated.  What's he answer to this `SELECT b+1 AS a, a+1 AS b`?  If you want to define something, the use it in another expression, it just needs to be isolated in a different scope, be that a CTE, sub-query, applied function, whatever...

Comment: @JimMaas Of course your first option or a subselect version are a more correct way; I just also thought that using the case clause three times would help get the idea that the content of the alias is not visible from the same query.